# Reseting Counter Value based on Date

Tags: sql, oracle, case

When querying an Oracle database, I am building a table that calculates the age licenses of each year it has been in existence from its issue_date. Something like:

```
LICENSE_NUMBER    ISSUE_ANNIVERSARY   LICENSE_AGE
1234              13-JUN-83           1
1234              13-JUN-84           2
1234              13-Jun-85           3
1234              13-Jun-86           4
1234              13-Jun-87           5
1234              13-Jun-88           6
1234              13-Jun-89           7
```

I have been given one caveat. When the ISSUE_ANNIVERSARY hits 1986, I have to reset the age back to 1. So, my desired result would look like this:

```
LICENSE_NUMBER    ISSUE_ANNIVERSARY   LICENSE_AGE
1234              13-JUN-83           1
1234              13-JUN-84           2
1234              13-Jun-85           3
1234              13-Jun-86           1
1234              13-Jun-87           2
1234              13-Jun-88           3
1234              13-Jun-89           4
```

My approach is to set a condition CASE clause to reset the LICENSE_AGE when the ISSUE_ANNIVERSARY contains 1986 in the year however I don't think I have the syntax correct. I've tried a few methods, but keeping getting errors. My latest attempt is below. I am not hung up on this CASE approach, however I have to keep in mind that I have licenses issued before 1986, during 1986 and after 1986, so I figured a condition would work best. Any suggestions to get this going is appreciated!

```
WITH LICENSE (license_number, issue_anniversary, expiry_date, license_age) AS 
    (
    SELECT lic.license_number, lic.issue_date, lic.expiry_date, 1
    FROM license_table lic

    UNION ALL

    SELECT license_number, ADD_MONTHS(issue_anniversary, 12), expiry_date,  
    CASE 
     WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(issue_anniversary, 12) = 1986 THEN 1
    ELSE
     license_age + 1
    END
    FROM   license
    WHERE expiry_date <= sysdate and license_number = 1234
    )

SELECT license_number,
       issue_anniversary,
       license_age     
FROM   license
```

Comment: What makes you think that your approach is not correct?

Comment: (1) Storing both the date and the age violates third normal form, and risks loss of R/I if they get out of sync.  Consider storing only the date. You can include the age as a computed column or using a view instead. (2) Have you considered a License_Year table? You could then join to it to determine how to compute the age. Otherwise you'll be stuck hardcoding 1986 into your code.

Comment: @JohnWu: (1) they are not storing it, they are computing it on the fly in a recursive query.

Comment: @GMB. Good question. I feel like approach is correct, theoretically. At least, if I draw from my python background, I'm in the right ballpark, however I am getting various different errors, depending on the approach I try and so I felt like I needed to ask. Also, thanks for clarifying. Yes, I want to calculate the field, not store it.

Comment: @Mike: at first sight your code looks good to me. You should test it, and advise if you have some specific issue with it.

Comment: @GMB thanks for the encouragement. As I was getting so many errors (and my sql is very intermediate at this point) I think I missed something. Despite what I posted for code, the one I ran had a THEN condition of "THEN license_age = 1" to match the "ELSE license_age + 1" The THEN condition errored and I should not have included 'license_age =" and just left it at "THEN 1" as in my code above. I feel silly now as my code actually does work. Many thanks for taking your time to point out my flaw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by license_number,
                                       case when ISSUE_ANNIVERSARY < date '1986-01-01' then 1 else 0 end
                          order by ISSUE_ANNIVERSARY
                         ) as license_age
from license_table lt;
```

Comment: @George Linoff. Thanks for your suggestion. I haven't used the OVER clause along with partitioning before and I have been playing around with some code using it. Although I solved my own issue, I am definitely learning something useful and I believe I could use your logic. Thanks for contributing!